# How does this code work correctly?

Tags: php, file-manager

What does this code do ?
I can't understand the while loop mainly ! 
mainly can't understand $total--

```
function getNiceFileSize($file, $digits = 2)
{
    if(is_file($file)){
        $filePath = $file;
        if(!realpath($filePath)){
            $filePath = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . $filePath;
        }
        $fileSize = filesize($filePath);
        $sizes = array("TB", "GB", "MB", "KB", "B");
        $total = count($sizes);
        while ($total-- && $fileSize > 1024){
            $fileSize /= 1024;
        }
        return round($fileSize, $digits). " " . $sizes[$total];
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$total--` is the same as `$total -= 1`, which is the same as `$total = $total -1`. This is known as the [decrement operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php). You are probably familiar with the increment operator when looking at `for` loops, such as `for ($i = 0, $i++, $i < 10)`.

The loop can be rewritten as `while ($total = $total -1 && $fileSize > 1024)`, which means "while $total is still a truthy value (in this case, a number > 0) and $fileSize is > 1024".

Comment: Thank you for useful answer

Comment: @amir if this answered your question you should mark it as accepted for others who might have the same question.